# security on "pattern:web-service-proxy" in mule

Tags: web-services, security, mule

I'm using "pattern:web-service-proxy" in mule and I redirect old wsdl in another version on news address wsdl in mule server.

I will use new address of wsdl in my web services.
I want to put security on new address in mule server, such as:
I limited my wsdl that every one don't allow to use my wsdl. (user with specific ip allow to use it)
I set username & password for use wsdl,...

please tell me how to set this security in mule config?

Comment: Do you need a user password based authorization mechanism or do you want to accept request coming from certains IP addresses?

Comment: I want to put filter such as below linke:
"http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/Mule+Filter+Processor"
but my mule stdio doesn't have this feature.
I want to limit user with their Ip address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the feature described by that link is not available within mule the underling principle is still valid.

You can leverage the expression filter by doing something like the following:

```
<expression-filter expression="#[groovy:'${allowed}'.contains(message.getInboundProperty('MULE_REMOTE_CLIENT_ADDRESS').substring(message.getInboundProperty('MULE_REMOTE_CLIENT_ADDRESS').indexOf('/')+1, message.getInboundProperty('MULE_REMOTE_CLIENT_ADDRESS').indexOf(':')))]" doc:name="Expression"/>
```

being allowed a property placeholder that at runtime will be replaced by a list (i.e. comma separated) of allowed IPs.

Comment: sorry Genjosanzo, correct of link is :
http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/Mule+Filter+Processor

Comment: Yes, I figured that out. AFAICT this link is either outdated or refer to a feature that has not been implemented yet. That said the approach I'm suggesting in my answer provides the same functionality of the filter described in that link